# Solving systems of equations in 3 variables

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I am trying to solve (in $\mathbb{C}$) the following systems of equations in 3 variables:

> $$x+y+z=0$$
>   $$xy+yz+xz=c-c^2$$
>   $$xyz=3c^2$$
>   where, $c$ is some fixed non-zero constant.

I tried substituting in $x=-y-z$ into the third equation, and then solved for $z$, but the problem is that this is not a nice answer and so substituting this into the second equation leads to a disaster.
I am assuming there is a neat trick as this looks like a special case of systems of equations in 3 variables!?

Is it also correct to assume that there is a unique solution for $x,y,z$ since there are 3 equations and 3 unknowns?

Answer (score 2):

Write your system in the form
$$xy-(x+y)^2=c-c^2$$
and $$-xy(x+y)=3c^2$$
Substituting $$x+y=a$$ $$xy=b$$ so you will get
$$b-a^2=c-c^2$$ and $$-ab=3c^2$$
Can you proceed?
Eliminating $b$ you will get for $a$:
$$0=a^3+a(c-c^2)+3c^2$$

Comment: I managed to get to your last step, but then there are no easy roots of $a$ and so would you not have to use the cubic formula, which would also result in a big mess?

Comment: Yes this is right, since $c$ is a constant, you can solve your equation for $c$ and discover the roots as a function of $a$

Answer (score 1):

There is a classical 'trick' one can use for these types of systems of equations, namely [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas). Note that
$$
(\lambda - x)(\lambda - y)(\lambda - z) = \lambda^3 - (x + y + z) \lambda^2 + (xy +yz + xz)\lambda - xyz.
$$
Hence, $x, y, z$ are the three roots of the polynomial equation
$$
\lambda^3 + (c - c^2) \lambda - 3c^2 = 0.
$$
Denoting the roots of this equation by $\lambda_1,\lambda_2, \lambda_3$, this shows that the only solutions of the original system of equations are permutations of $(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3)$. Moreover, as there is an explicit (albeit rather complicated) expression for the roots of a cubic polynomial, one can find the solutions of the above equation.

Answer (score 0):

Let $z=-x-y$. Substitute this into the second and third equation. Multiplying the second by $y$ and subtracting the third we obtain
$$
2xy^2 + c(cy + 3c - y)=0.
$$
For $y=0$ we have $x=y=c=0$. Otherwise we can substitute $x=-c(cy+3c-y)/(2y^2)$. This yields only one polynomial equation in $y$ and $c$, namely, 
$$
c^3( - y^2 - 6y - 9) + 2c^2y(y + 3) + cy^2(2y^2 - 6y - 1) - 2y^4=0.
$$
I doesn't get easier than that. But it can be solved
over the complex numbers. One particular solution is $c=1$ and $2y^3+3=0$, $z=3/y^2$, $x=-3/(2y^2)$. However, it is not correct that a non-linear system in $n$ variables with $n$ equations  has a unique solution.